# Root Category not showing filters

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layered-navigation

I have shown root category on frontend and all the products are coming fine. But the filters are not showing in the sidebar. I have used layout `2 column left`.

```
<reference name="content">

<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
</block>


</reference>
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.categories" template="catalog/navigation/sidebar.phtml"/>
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
    </block>
```

Can anyone help and share how to call filters. It is actually calling just the heading. The category is is anchor yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to :

Product-> Categories (Select your category) -> Display Settings

and turn on "Anchor" to yes.

Hope this will work for you

I have added filter here: https://zitomer-upgrade.aastaging.us/beauty

```
EDIT: Yes this is the right answer, but the reason same stuff was not working for me was because of manadev filters used. So I have to use the mana filters in xml
```